# How to pass parameter to dataflow template for pipeline construction

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying make a ancestor query like this [example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples/blob/master/python/dataflow_examples/cookbook/datastore_wordcount.py) and transfer it to template version.
The problem is that the parameter ancestor_id is for the function make_query during pipeline construction.
If I don't pass it when create and stage the template, I will get **RuntimeValueProviderError: RuntimeValueProvider(option: ancestor_id, type: int).get() not called from a runtime context**. But if I pass it at template creating, it seems like a StaticValueProvider that never change when I execute the template.
What is the correct way to pass parameter to template for pipeline construction?

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import query_pb2
from googledatastore import helper as datastore_helper
from googledatastore import PropertyFilter

class Test(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument('--ancestor_id', type=int)

def make_query(ancestor_id):
    ancestor = entity_pb2.Key()
    datastore_helper.add_key_path(ancestor, KIND, ancestor_id)
    query = query_pb2.Query()
    datastore_helper.set_kind(query, KIND)
    datastore_helper.set_property_filter(query.filter, '__key__', PropertyFilter.HAS_ANCESTOR, ancestor)
    return query

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
test_options = pipeline_options.view_as(TestOptions)
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipline_options) as p:
  entities = p | ReadFromDatastore(PROJECT_ID, make_query(test_options.ancestor_id.get()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems.

1. The `ValueProvider.value.get()` method can only run in a run-time method like `ParDo.process()`. See [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#modifying-your-code-to-use-runtime-parameters).
2. Further, your challenge is that your are using Google Cloud Datastore IO (a query from datastore). As of today (May 2018),
   the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates#pipeline-io-and-runtime-parameters) indicates that, Datastore IO is **NOT** accepting runtime template parameters yet.

For python, particularly,

> > The following connectors accept runtime parameters.
> >       File-based IOs: textio, avroio, tfrecordio

A **workaround**: you probably can first run a query without any templated parameters to get a PCollection of entities. At this time, since any transformers can accept a templated parameter you might be able to use it as a **filter**. But this depends on your use case and it may not applicable to you.

Comment: Does this means I need to fetch all table then filter it?

Comment: It's an alternative I can think of. Maybe there are other possible workarounds. If you can use a compile-time input parameter (not run time) this is not a problem. But I guess you do need it at run time, right?

Comment: Seems template can only use run time parameter, so my workaround is not to use template...